# Preserving/remapping intid based relations when moving Plone sites

Tags: plone, zope

I'm migrating some Plone 4 sites and noticed a problem when moving the entire site after migration. The actual migration is fine - relatedItems and other relations are handled well by the migration scripts. But the problem is my staging environment has a different ZODB mount structure than the destination production environment, and this seems to break intid based relations. For instance it might come in as /dbXX/mysite and end up on /dbYY/mysite, which makes both the to_object and the from_object of a RelationValue inaccurate. I took a look at five.intid and it looks like it is based on the database oid which is perhaps dependent on the path?

I have been unable to find any information on how to handle this. I get the impression it just isn't meant to work with changes to the path, but I don't really have the option of not changing it here. The path is not arbitrary, it is based on actual ZODB mount points. I am considering two options which I want to solicit feedback on:

1. For background, I am moving a zexp to a staging environment in Plone 4 (identical buildout with p4 production), then moving the entire Data.fs to a Plone 5 staging environment (identical buildout with p5 production), migrating, then moving zexp to production. When moving from Plone 4 to staging env, I could have the zope path mirror what it will be at the final destination. At this point relatedItems etc. should be UID based which won't change. The drawback here is that any intid relations from Plone 4 will break at this point, but I don't think there are many/any of those.
2. Creating a mapping of all relations based on the RelationCatalog and rebuild/cleanup. I'm thinking I would do this by noting the from_attribute, from_path, and to_path, and recreating relations with the new intids after the final move. I might have to know something about the structure of the from_attribute at this point. Any other drawbacks?

Comment: I posted a link to your question on the Plone forum, https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-preserving-remapping-intid-based-relations-when-moving-plone-sites/4350

Comment: Is it necessary to use a ZEXP-file? They are said to generally be avoided for data-migration. Would be interesting to see, if the error occurs nevertheless, when you move the actual database, if possible.

Comment: I'm not using it for data migration. I'm copying to an identical setup in Plone 4, moving that entire database to Plone 5 buildout and doing the migration. Then I copy that site to production which is identical to that staging environment. We have several sites on both our Plone 4 and Plone 5 buildouts so it's necessary to extract each site in this way (not going to migrate them all at the same time).